# Totals not printing correctly and displaying zeros in java program

Tags: java, methods

Hi everyone I have almost finished this program except that my totals are not displaying their correct values they are only displaying zeros. I've looked through for ages and find why this is happening. Can someone please help me here? The totals are calculated in the getTotals() method near the bottom. Thanks!

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Assignment1Q2 {

    int age = 0;
    char gender;
    char show;
    char choice = 'y';
    int over30MY = 0, over30FY = 0, under30MY = 0, under30FY = 0;
    int over30MN = 0, over30FN = 0, under30MN = 0, under30FN = 0;
    int totalCalls = 0;
    int totalWatchers = 0;
    float perTotalWatchers = 0.0f;
    float perU30M = 0.0f, perU30F = 0.0f, perO30M = 0.0f, perO30F = 0.0f, perTotalF = 0.0f,  perTotalM = 0.0f;
    float perTotalU30 = 0.0f, perTotalO30 = 0.0f, perTotal = 0.0f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {       

        Assignment1Q2 a = new Assignment1Q2(); //creates an objects to call non-static methods

        a.Info(); //Prints student info

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Thanks for your call\nPlease answer some questions");
        System.out.println("");

        while(a.choice == 'y') {

            a.collectData();
        } // end of while loop

        a.getTotals();
        a.printTotals();

    }//end of main

    public void Info() { //Prints student Info

        System.out.println("Name:");
        System.out.println("Student Id:");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Tutor:");
        System.out.println("Tutorial:");
    }

    public void collectData() {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); //collects data from user

        //ask questions
        System.out.println("What is your age?\n");
        age = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Male or Female (Enter M or Y)");
        gender = userInput.next().charAt(0);
        gender = Character.toLowerCase(gender);

        System.out.println("Do you watch the show regularly? (Enter Y or N)");
        show = userInput.next().charAt(0);
        show = Character.toLowerCase(show);

        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another person's details? (Enter Y or N)");
        choice = userInput.next().charAt(0);
        choice = Character.toLowerCase(choice);

        //store data
        if((age >= 30) && (gender == 'm') && (show == 'y')) {       
            over30MY++;             
        }
        else if((age >= 30) && (gender == 'f') && (show == 'y')) {
            over30FY++;
        }
        else if((age < 30) && (gender == 'm') && (show == 'y')) {
            under30MY++;
        }
        else if((age < 30) && (gender == 'f') && (show == 'y')) {
            under30FY++;
        }
        else if((age >= 30) && (gender == 'm') && (show == 'n')) {
            over30MN++;
        }
        else if((age >= 30) && (gender == 'f') && (show == 'n')) {
            over30FN++;
        }
        else if((age < 30) && (gender == 'm') && (show == 'n')) {
            under30MN++;
        }
        else if((age < 30) && (gender == 'f') && (show == 'n')) {
            under30FN++;

        }//end of if else

    }//end of collectData

        public void getTotals() {//calculate totals for printing

            totalCalls = over30MY + over30FY + under30MY + under30FY + over30MN + over30FN + under30MN + under30FN;

            totalWatchers = over30MY + over30FY + under30MY + under30FY;

            perTotalWatchers = ((totalWatchers / totalCalls) * 100); //rounds percentage to nearest whole number

            if(totalWatchers > 0) {

                perU30F = ((under30FY / totalWatchers) * 100); //Total Under 30 Females
                perU30M = (under30MY / totalWatchers) * 100; //Total Under 30 Males
                perO30F = ((over30FY / totalWatchers) * 100); //Total Over 30 Females
                perO30M = ((over30MY / totalWatchers) * 100); //Total Over 30 Males

                perTotalF = Math.round(perU30F + perO30F); //Total Females
                perTotalM = Math.round(perU30M + perO30M); //Total Males

                perTotalU30 = Math.round(perU30F + perU30M); //Total Under 30
                perTotalO30 = Math.round(perO30F + perO30M); //Total Over 30
                perTotal = Math.round(perTotalF + perTotalM); //Total 

            }
            else
            System.out.println("There was no-one who watched the show");

        }//end of getTotals

        public void printTotals () { //Prints the Totals

            System.out.println("Total People called is "+totalCalls);
            System.out.println("Number of people who watch the show regularly is "+totalWatchers);
            System.out.println("Percentage of those who watch the show is regularly is "+perTotalWatchers+"%");
            System.out.println("");

            final Object[][] table = new String[4][];
            table[0] = new String[] { "Gender", "%Under 30", "%30 or Over", "%Total" };
            table[1] = new String[] { "Female", " "+perU30F, " "+perO30F, " "+perTotalF };
            table[2] = new String[] { "Male", " "+perU30M, " "+perO30M, " "+perTotalM };
            table[3] = new String[] { "Total", " "+perTotalU30, " "+perTotalO30, " "+perTotal };

            for (final Object[] row : table) {
                System.out.format("%15s%15s%15s%15s\n", row);
            }

        }//end of printTotals

}// end of class
```

Comment: Don't compare `String` ( or any kind of `Object` ) using `==`, use `equals` method !

Comment: @Julien The OP is comparing primitive characters rather than `Objects`

Answer (score 1):

Youre doing integer division. Ensure at least one the operands is a floating point number to avoid truncation of numbers after the decimal point. Change this

```
perU30F = ((under30FY / totalWatchers) * 100);
```

to

```
perU30F = ((under30FY / (double)totalWatchers) * 100);
```

Apply the same to other divisions

In Java, `int/int` will always return an `int`. To get a result with decimals, one of the two operands (or both) must be a decimal number.